# How does MQTT protocol work

Tags: mqtt

Can someone explain in details the working of MQTT protocol?
Is there a persistent connection between broker and publisher/subscriber?
Or does the broker establish connections as and when required?

Comment: This type of question is off topic for Stack Overflow, I suggest you have a look at the spec which is linked to from http://mqtt.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Can someone explain in details the working of MQTT protocol?

MQTT is a Pub/Sub centralized-broker protocol that is usually implemented over TCP, and by usually I mean that the specification does not force the underlying protocol to be TCP, but is the most used one. Websocket implementations are also available.

### Is there a persistent connection between broker and publisher/subscriber?

Yes, the TCP connection is made when you send the MQTT Connect message, which is the first packet you need to send regardless of what kind of client you are. MQTT has ways of detecting if this connection has broken and act in consequence. Sessions can be resumed after disconnections, so closing the TCP/MQTT connection does not mean that the session will be lost.

### Does the broker establish connections as and when required?

The TCP handshake is sent before the MQTT connect message. Most of the libraries will handle this for you, but if you are trying to create your own library, then you obviously need to establish a connection before sending the Connect message.